# Live SDK for .Net 3.5

Tags: c#, winforms, onedrive, download, live-sdk

I am developing a winform application targeting .net framework 3.5 . I want to provide support for uploading and downloading to onedrive from my application.But when I searched the internet, I only found live SDK for .Net 4.5 . So, is there a live SDK for .Net 3.5? If not, then is there any other alternative? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try googling?

Comment: Any solid reason not using .Net4.5?

Comment: I tried google but only found Live SDK for .Net 4.5 . And my whole application is built in VS 2008.i.e why I can't use .Net 4.5